# PHP Mysql Ajax login page not checking details

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I've been working through a tutorial provided here: http://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Log-In-Form-Log-Out-Script-Cookies-Sessions-User-Profile I have tried to contact the video make several times but no response.

I'm using the video to create a login page for my site, allowing logged in users post to a blog.

I'm using the code in login.php here: http://superraddm.com/login.php

However the page doesn't actually verify if the user exists or not, it accepts any entry.

I assume the failure is somewhere in the ajax portion, most probably here:

```
if(isset($_POST["e"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES AND SANITIZE
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = md5($_POST['p']);
// GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($e == "" || $p == ""){
    echo "login_failed";
    exit();
```

I think the $e and $p variables are not getting passed correctly, so the code doesn't even get to 'login failed'.

To test I changed the 3rd line from bottom to:

```
if($e == "A" || $p == "A"){
    echo "login_failed";
```

And attempted to login using A as both username and password, and it still logs in.

Comment: Can you do `print_r($_POST)` just before `if(isset($_POST["e"]))` and show the result?

Comment: @Pierre-Jean Attempting, but in dream weaver i get  syntax error on the if(isset line:

'<?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
print_r($_POST)

if(isset($_POST["e"])){
 // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
 include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");'

Comment: I think you forgot `;`.

Comment: @Pierre-Jean Done, refresh the page. I think you're onto something.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-Jean Any further advice? I'm in a bit over my head here. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Done, refresh the page"? Did you try `print_r($_POST); if(isset($_POST["e"])){ ...` (notice the `;` after `print_r`)? What is the result?

Comment: My apologies. Yes, i added the above. What i mean by refresh the page, is that the page is live here: [link](www.superraddm.com/login.php)

Hopefully you can tell me what I should expect to see.

Either the result is nothing, or the next page loads to quickly for me to verify it. Thanks again.